# Samsung Galaxy Tab A Keyboard Going Haywire

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-a

Whenever I write on Word with this tablet, the keyboard always malfunctions, and as I type, the keyboard will often capitalize the letters randomly without me telling it to, or it will finish my words for me. For example if I typed board, and hit space, it would go back and continue my word to say boardgames. Very annoying. Where does this problem come from and how do I solve it? 
Thankyou

Answer (score -1):

Clear the data from Google keyboard. Go to settings, apps, Google keyboard, clear data.